# Proper use of a for loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I am taking a c++ class right now and I know that a for loop will work like this but I was wondering if it was "normal" or "proper"

```
for (int i = 0; getline(cin, input); i++)
```

Should this instead be

```
int i = 0;
while (getline(cin, input))
    i++;
```

I'm just wondering because I know a for loop is supposed to be a counter loop but the condition for this one does not have to do with an amount of times going through that i controls.

Comment: Too subjective of a question, voted to close. Possibly better at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Surprisingly, it is possible to build a reasonably objective argument in favor of the `for` loop :)

Comment: my personal rule of thumb is: if the running index is needed after the loop, use while, else use for. But since every for can be expressed as while it's just a matter of style

Comment: @Kristian : Questions like this are low hanging fruit for easy rep. The rep of the people answering doesn't change the fact that the question is subjective.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the rules of the for loop are quite simple. As long as you meet the rules, the syntax can be whatever you want.

Of the two, just pick the one you find most readable.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, there is no "proper" way to write a `for` loop: you can leave out any combination of the three parts blank (in fact, K&R suggest leaving all three blank to implement a "forever" loop), and there is no hard requirement to have a stopping condition depend on the loop counter.

One advantage of the `for` loop over the `while` loop is that you can freely use `continue` inside the body, without a fear of forgetting to increment your counter. This may help readability for loops with lots of embedded `continue` statements.

Answer (score 3):

It is fine, but as a matter of **style** I'd prefer the `while` loop.

For loops are generally used for bounded iteration, where you know the number of iterations in advance, and while loops are used in more general situations.

Answer (score 2):

Both will work the same. However, it is not all about what they do, it is also about how to make it easier for a "human" to understand the code.

You can think of your source code as a detailed document, talking about how to do a specific task. In fact so detailed that even a compiler, i.e. a dumb machine, can understand it. In other words, you write code for other people, getting compiled to machine code is a pleasant side-effect.

With that in view, using syntactic constructs in a surprising way is not the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

They both work.

The `while` statement is the way most people would write it, and it's easy to understand. The `for` statement is a little shorter, but most people would have to look twice to understand what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

While I wouldn't normally think of a `for` loop as restricted to a counted loop with a pre-specified boundary, I *would* normally think of it as being one where the `increment` part of the loop was directly involved with progressing toward the loop finishing.

Just for example, I think it's perfectly reasonable to walk through a linked list with something like:

```
for (ptr = list_head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
    process(ptr->data);
```